# NodeJS Sails FrameWork Lock Critical Code

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I want to know how can I defend from multiple request that exec Process
that :
 1.retrive data.
 2.do some logic.
 3.make updates on many tables.

If many users exec the process, I want only 1 request proccessing until finish update data in DB and all another request wait until the process finishes and after the system can continue. Like LOCK or Synchronized

Answer (score 0):

You can use transactions for the. There is a module for this:

https://github.com/postmanlabs/sails-mysql-transactions